# I can't install Android Studio

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio

I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

My JDK version is 1.8.0_31.

I downloaded [Android Studio archive](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), unpacked it and ran a studio.sh file. But every time the installation begins an error occurs:

> Refresh Sources:
>     Failed to fetch URL http ://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, reason: File not found
>     Fetched Add-ons List successfully
>     Refresh Sources
>     Failed to fetch URL http ://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml, reason: File not found
>   Refresh Sources:
>     Failed to fetch URL http ://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml, reason: File not found
>   There is nothing to install or update.
>   The following SDK components were not installed: build-tools-21.1.1, source-21, sys-img-x86-addon-google_apis-google-21, extra-android-m2repository, android-21, extra-google-m2repository, addon-google_apis-google-21, platform-tools

Moreover, when I run the studio.sh file following text appears in terminal:

> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0

Also I tried to install the Android Studio from Paolo Rotolo's repository, but the same problem occurs.

I am rookie in Ubuntu, so I hope only for your help.

Comment: Have you tried this? `sudo chown -R <username> .android`

Comment: Can you access [the requested file](http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml) from your browser?

Comment: @JoanColmenero yes, I've tried this, but it doesn't help me.

Comment: @StenSoft yes, I can

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also met this problem. Even I can download the xml files from browser, the android update sdk process keep reporting file not found. A search from google leads me to here:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=76268

The first anwser reminds me of permission problem of ~/.android. I checked, and found that this hidden directory is not owned by me. Change the owner of the directory solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Its not that tough actually, just follow the following steps:

1. first of all make sure your ubuntu is uptodate. open >Unity>Software updater.
2. Install latest Jdk - in my case its Java8

Installing java

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

3. Make it default version

   sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default

Installing Android Studio

Download Android Studio from here, use All Android Studio Packages
Extract the archive file into an appropriate location for your applications, eg: /opt. Use the filename of your downloaded archive, in my example android-studio-ide-141.2178183-linux.zip

```
sudo unzip android-studio-ide-141.2178183-linux.zip -d /opt
```

To launch Android Studio, navigate to the **/opt/android-studio/bin directory** in a terminal and execute **./studio.sh**. Or use a desktop file, see below. Make sure you type "./studio.sh"

You may want to add /opt/android-studio/bin to your PATH environmental variable so that you can start Android Studio from any directory.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo studio.sh
```

running it as root solved for me

Comment: -1, this will generate some permission issues, like chowning the `~./android` directory (which should be owned by the current user instead), aswell as other related risks